# How do I send an authentication header via an image?

Tags: php

I'm completely new to php but managed to find a script that will produce the HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized message box

This is the message box:

[image]

I've heard and seen that you can make this message box be sent through an image. How do i go about doing that?

When done, the steps should be:

I post image.jpg
The authentication message shows up

I know it involves me having a website (example.com). Then on the website i have a folder (example.com/folder) and in that folder i have the image (example.com/folder/image.jpg). What php script do i put in the folder that will result in the image generating the authentication message?

Comment: What do you mean by "sent through an image"?  Are you just trying to protect an image file with a password box?

Comment: No, i mean directly through an image. Heres an example site that does exactly what im trying to do:http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery. If you scroll down to their Example 10 you'll see as soon as the image is shown, the Authentication Header message pops up.

Comment: Do you mean the "display image" button on this page: http://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/?  That's just a PHP script that uses [`gd`](http://php.net/gd) to create an image with text on it.  You don't actually have an image file, you have a PHP script that echos an image: `<img src="img.php" />`.

Comment: So how do i make the <img src="img.php" /> bring up the authentication image exactly? I'm REALLY inexperienced at this

Comment: So, you *do* just want to protect the image from being shown until a password is entered?

Comment: You said you have code to make the auth message box, so just put that in the `img.php` file.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Or at least the prompt doesnt go away until the password is entered, regardless of if the image is still visible. Whichever is more simple

Comment: This is just basic auth.  You don't even need PHP for it.

Comment: So you mean the end result is                                      <img src="<?php
    if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
        header("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"Image.gif\"");
        header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
        // only reached if authentication fails
        print "Sorry - you need valid credentials granted access to the private area!\n";
        exit;
    } else {
        // only reached if authentication succeeds
        print "Welcome to the private area, {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']} - you used {$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']} as your password.";
    }
?>"/>   ?

Comment: @Brad: Yeah!  I guess you're right!  You can use `.htpassword` for this.

Comment: @user3112748: Brad's right.  You can use your webserver to do this without PHP! :)

Comment: But how do i do with the PHP? I want to learn as much as actually execute. Where did i mess up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said before in comments, it has nothing to do with PHP.

The button in your example just set the image URL. But that URL is protected by HTTP Basic Authentication.

To do this just create 2 files in the image folder : [.htaccess and .htpasswd](http://www.thesitewizard.com/apache/password-protect-directory.shtml)

And add HTML and Javascript code like the one on the website :

```
<img src="" id="downloadImg" alt=""/>
<input type="button" value="Display Image" id="displayImage" onclick="document.getElementById('downloadImg').src='/protected-folder/image.jpg';"/>
```